# Attach to Rider debugger through command line

Tags: powershell, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am looking for a way to attach the debugger in Rider through CLI. I noticed that when the debugger attaches, it emits the following

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\Rider\ch-1\173.3994.2442\bin\runnerw.exe C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\Rider\ch-1\173.3994.2442\lib\ReSharperHost\JetBrains.Debugger.Worker64.exe 61962
```

I wrote a PowerShell script that mimics the output above but executing it didn't attach the debugger. I tried looking for help commands on those two executables but nothing returned.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is actually supported today, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Working_with_the_IDE_Features_from_Command_Line.html#arguments

for example:

```sh
PID=$(ps aux | grep -v grep | grep 'dotnet exec .*/Mugen.dll' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2)
rider attach-to-process $PID Mugen.sln
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 4.17.2018, per JetBrains Rider support, this functionality is currently not supported.